# Getting contains to work with multiple words

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm working on search and want to get it error-proof.

let's say we have 3 strings: `containsText` that contains 2 words I'm looking for in `fullTextShort` and `fullTextLong`

My func `contains` works with `fullTextShort` as the words that I'm looking for are right after each other, but it doesn't work with `fullTextLong` where there's a world in between.

How to get the func to return true for both cases?

```
struct ContainsFuncView: View {
    let fullTextShort = "I like pineapple"
    let fullTextLong = "I like green pineapple"
    let containsText = "like pineapple"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            contains(type: "Short")
            contains(type: "Long")
            }
    }
    
    func contains(type: String) -> Text {
        var containsInFullText: Bool = false
        
        if type == "Short" {
            containsInFullText = fullTextShort.localizedStandardContains(containsText)
        }
        
        else if type == "Long" {
            containsInFullText = fullTextLong.localizedStandardContains(containsText)
        }

        return Text("\(containsInFullText ? "Contains" : "Doesn't contain") in fullText\(type)").foregroundColor(containsInFullText ? .green : .red)
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split `containsText` at the space. Then test if any or all words are in the text:

```
containsInFullText = containsText.components(separatedBy: " ").contains { fullTextShort.localizedStandardContains($0) }


containsInFullText = containsText.components(separatedBy: " ").allSatisfy { fullTextShort.localizedStandardContains($0) }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the searched text into words and the reduce the search results for each word so the search returns true only when all words are found

```swift
let words = containsText.split(separator: " ")

if type == "Short" {
    containsInFullText = words.reduce(true) { contains, word in
        contains && fullTextShort.localizedStandardContains(word)
    }
}

else if type == "Long" {
    containsInFullText = words.reduce(true) { contains, word in
        contains && fullTextLong.localizedStandardContains(word)
    }
}
```

If you want to return true when at least one word is found, swap the `&&` to `||` and the initial value to `false`

```swift
if type == "Short" {
    containsInFullText = words.reduce(false) { contains, word in
        contains || fullTextShort.localizedStandardContains(word)
    }
}

else if type == "Long" {
    containsInFullText = words.reduce(false) { contains, word in
        contains || fullTextLong.localizedStandardContains(word)
    }
}
```

Comment: Swift has allSatisfy which (presumably) does not continue the loop if an element does not match the predicate, as opposed to your code.